# Wordpress Image Gallery Using External Images

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery

I would like to know of any known image or video gallery plugins that use external media sources instead of having to upload via wordpress media library.

Worst case, is there a plugin that can performed a scheduled / updates only import from a file server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do u mean by `only import form a file server`

Comment: "updates only" so delta load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [code](http://www.portablehtml.com/2013/04/the-issus-battle-gallery.html) jointly with [ImageZone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imagezone/). 
With ImageZone you can collect external images and share them, while the code will render them into html. The code looks like:

```
// where do you want to add the gallery 
<div id="GalleryId"></div>
  <style>...</style>
  // this is generated by imagezone
  <script type="text/json" id="GalleryId">...</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setup(gid){
    }
    setup("GalleryId");
  </script>
```

and you could make it a wp shortcode